Difference between terraform resources "azuread_application" & "azuread_application_registration"
Topic: Azure Terraform
Question:
I’m writing a Terraform module to create an Azure App Configuration service to store configuration values as key-value pairs. After setting up the service, I want to query it via REST API calls to retrieve the keys and values. While researching how to do this, I found out that to communicate with Azure via API calls, we need to register our app using Azure App Registrations, obtain a client ID, secret, and auth token, and use these credentials to make the API requests.
In Terraform, there are the azuread_application and azuread_application_registration resources, both of which are used to create Service Principals. However, I’m unclear on the difference between these two resources and when to use each. Could someone of you provide a detailed but simple explanation?
I would like to know the difference between the two and help with writing a tf module

As mentioned in the documentation of azuread_application_registration and azuread_application, both resources can be used to manage an application registration within Azure Active Directory.
azuread_application is a more comprehensive version as compared to azuread_application_registration.
PS:

Both resources should not be used together when managing the same application.

